# PHP XMLNode, DOMnode Xpath selection predicate for a grandchild attribute value

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I have some xml

```
<div> First Element
 <div>
  <level3 name="fred">
  </level3>
 </div>
</div>
<div> Second Element
 <div>
  <level3 name="dave">
  </level3>
 </div>
</div>
<div> Third Element
 <div>
  <level3 name="jim">
  </level3>
 </div>
</div>
<div> Fifth Element
 <div>
  <level3 name="mike">
  </level3>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the xml (as a string, including the xml tags) from a specific top level div element based in its grandchilds name at level3.

So to get the top div above the level3 node with the name of jim I have been looking at things like:

```
$sname="jim";
$spath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// Find a div with a child div with a level3 with a matching attribute name. 
$spexp = "//div[./div/level3[contains(@name,\"$sname\")]]";
$story = $spath->evaluate("$spexp");
echo $story->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
```

I have tried various combinations - including 'exists' in the predicate which I am sure is basic xslt, but not in PHP(!).

I have googled loads... but predicates going down past the immediate level hasn't come up, and it seems PHP's xpath has its own flavour, so general XPath stuff isn't always useful.

Comment: Make sure that the close quote is in `<level3 name="fred>`

Comment: You don't say how you're creating your doc, but if this is the complete document then you'll need to use `loadHTML`, since there are multiple root nodes. You might also need to suppress warnings about the non-standard `<level3>` tags, if those are part of the actual source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath was OK, this just removes the first bit inside the first `[` as it's not needed.

To output the XML, you need to use `saveXML()` with the node you want to export all of the XML tags as well...

```
$sname="jim";
$spath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// Find a div with a child div with a level3 with a matching attribute name.
$spexp = "//div[div/level3[contains(@name,\"$sname\")]]";
$story = $spath->evaluate("$spexp");
echo $doc->saveXML($story->item(0)). "\n";
```

Gives...

```
<div> Third Element
 <div>
  <level3 name="jim">
  </level3>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers - I could swear I tried that, I went through so many combinations! But clearly not!!